# LLDB: Setting a breakpoint for malloc_error_break through the console

Tags: c++, lldb

I'm running into some malloc-related issues in my code:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x103401e28: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I've tried things like:

```
(lldb) breakpoint set malloc_error_break
error: invalid combination of options for the given command
```

How do I set this breakpoint using the terminal? I've searched online and only found results involving Xcode.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are familiar with gdb, then this little cheat-sheet might help:

http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html

Also:

```
(lldb) help break set
```

will give you lots of information about setting breakpoints in lldb.

In this case:

```
(lldb) br set --name malloc_error_break
(lldb) br set -n malloc_error_break
```

or:

```
(lldb) b malloc_error_break
```

The first examples use `breakpoint set` which is a "true" lldb command - it uses flag options & values to distinguish the kinds of things you are trying to do.  `b`is a synthetic command that attempts to roughly recreate the gdb breakpoint syntax.

Comment: I'm still pretty new to both lldb and gdb, and I didn't realize that a "symbolic breakpoint" could mean a function. This clears up some  of the confusion I was having. Thank you very much for your help!