# How to “set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug” in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

My Qt5 app crashes when I hit the close window returning:

```
MyApp(28741,0x7fff7aa73000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fc40bc8e300: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

How to “set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug” in Qt Creator 4 (Mac OS)?

Should be better to do it via terminal in lldb/gdb, how?

Reference: [How to find reason for app crash on close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38170727/how-to-find-reason-for-app-crash-on-close)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Breakpoints window, right click->*Add Breakpoint...* change *Breakpoint type* to *Function name* and type `malloc_error_break` in *Funcion:*. Another way is to open Debugger Console (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>) and type `b malloc_error_break`.